# Cryptobiology? Biocryptology?

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence, knowledge, science

I have a friend who is a self-proclaimed cryptobiologist. Okay, maybe I don't, but if I did, I like to think she would have presented me with this puzzle:

> **Find the hidden message:**
>
> 441344•444422•132211 || 111313•114413•221311•221111•134422
>
> The message is the answer to "What is my favorite recently established (though somewhat contested) idea in biology?"

Also, this "friend" of mine is a much better biologist than she is a cryptologist. In fact, she is just about as novice in the "cryptology" scene as one can get.

---

**Update**

Hint:

*None of this is required in order to solve the puzzle, but it will probably help.*

> She told me "You silly chemist, to get you started, consider the elements hydrogen, nitrogen, oxygen, and the halogens; apply their strategy in your strategy. Or consider the behavior those nucleobases you're talking about.
> Do you notice any pattern in the numbers? It's small, but it's there. Each number by itself won't mean much.
> From there,
> 44 + 1 = 45
> 44 + 2 = 51
> 44 -  4 = 35
> 15 = E; 21 = F."

Comment: I don't know if the tags are right. I am not familiar enough with them here.

Comment: Is the Offspring reference a clue? Or just an edit note?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore No, it's not a clue, I just had my 1s and 3s backwards, and I wanted to point it out, and couldn't resist. I took it out because anyone that would have been affected by that change probably already saw it by now.

Comment: You should most likely tag this science as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The secret message (and answer to the recently established but contested biological theory) is:

> **RNA WORLD** (the idea that the precursors to life were self-replicating RNA molecules)

Reasoning/pitfalls below

---

Given the hints:

> The number strings are perhaps better interpreted as doublets (or maybe alleles based on the Punnett square hint).  If you break up the numbers into doublets, you could rewrite the string as:
> 44 13 44•44 44 22•13 22 11 || 11 13 13•11 44 13•22 13 11•22 11 11•13 44 22
>  This leaves only four possible doublets, 11, 13, 22, 44.  Possibly those could map to A, C, G, T.  But given the others hints, it looks like some sort of **bonding** may need to be used.  And a Punnett square represents crosses between two individuals and the potential offspring they could have, so perhaps we're supposed to cross two individuals with these "alleles" but there are still so many possible directions...

Thanks to the nice work by Element118, we can use:

> A [Polybius square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_square) to translate the pairs of numbers into DNA bases:
>
>  TCT TTG CGA || ACC ATC GCA GAA CTG

Then we need to:

> Transcribe the DNA (take its complementary strand as RNA, where A pairs with U and C pairs with G)
>
>  `TCT TTG CGA || ACC ATC GCA GAA CTG
>
>  AGA AAC GCU || UGG UAG CGU CUU GAC`

And since biology has its own:

> Triplicate code for converting RNA sequences to amino acid sequences (see pic below) and since amino acids can each be represented by a single letter (again, pic below), we must then translate the RNA sequence.
> [image]

Doing so, we get:

> `AGA AAC GCU || UGG UAG CGU CUU GAC
>
>  R   N   A      W   *   R   L   D`
>
>  Since there's no amino acid abbreviated "O", we switch the Stop codon to be an O.

Comment: This seems promising?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleic_acid_notation

Comment: Nice! The "O" actually does exist as a (rare) proteinogenic amino acid, [Pyrrolysine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrolysine), but you got the answer and I figured this wouldn't be terribly obvious.

Comment: Great answer to the puzzle in general, but [the hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_world#History) isn't exactly recent by any measure.

Comment: @MarchHo It's fairly recent that it became widely accepted, but you're right, I probably could have phrased that better. Plus, 1986 wasn't that long ago, relative to the scientific timeline.

Answer (score 6):

From Dan Russell we have:

> 44 13 44•44 44 22•13 22 || 11 13 13•11 44 13•22 13•22 11•13 44 22

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | A | B | C | D | E |
| **2** | F | G | H | I | J |
| **3** | K | L | M | N | O |
| **4** | P | Q | R | S | T |
| **5** | U | V | W | X | Y |

Interpreting the pairs as a letter from the above table we have:

> SCS•SSG•CG||ACC•ASC•GC•GA•CSG

I seriously think S should be something else, like T or U.

I suspect the J should be removed from the table, as J does not appear in the periodic table.

Comment: Can you show how you got that?

Comment: I added the table.

Comment: I/J should probably be combined, but [not because of the periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_square).

Comment: @Will I think the [more familiar one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tap_code) in English puts C/K together, but you guys both seem to have found plausible ideas.

Comment: "I suspect the J should be removed from the table" So do I "as J does not appear in the periodic table" Not for *that* reason, but because conventionally (even with English text), when the alphabet is put into 25 spaces, J is made to share with I. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_square#Basic_form If we do that, then 44 is not S but T, for the DNA nucleotide thymine. (But if this is RNA, U for uracil would be better, and U's at 45.)

Comment: @RosieF A little late for this response, but the reason I used T was because part of the puzzle was transcription from DNA to the complimentary RNA.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the numbers correlate to

> DNA bases - A, C, T and G.

All I got.

Comment: Well, that's a good start! I'd build on this.

Comment: But how did you find it out?

Comment: Well... it's a 4 element sequence and the subject is biology. Seems like a good guess.

Comment: I guessed that too... But no plausible words can seem to be formed. Perhaps this relates to the sequence 1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221......

Comment: I'm assuming that the letters themselves are relevant otherwise there's really no reason to bother with the biology theme? Maybe try converting to hex.

Comment: Could also be RNA by the same logic